# Which is better to use CachingConnectionFactory or caching in DefaultMessageListenerContainer?

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-jms

When using the spring-jms, there are 2 options given by spring for connection and session caching for performance gain.

1. Use the `CachingConnectionFactory` and cache the sessions, optionally you can cache producer and consumers as well.
2. Using the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` you can set the cacheLevel to [1:connection caching, 2:session caching], with 3 you can cache consumers as well.

My questions Is , why did spring created the redundant functionality ? which one is optimal and fast in terms of performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The caching factory is designed for short-lived sessions such as operations performed with a `JmsTemplate`.

It's generally not needed with the listener container (because its sessions are generally long-lived), unless you perform `JmsTemplate` operations on the container's thread - to participate in the container's transaction.

In that case, consumers should not be cached by the factory, especially if variable concurrency is in use. See the [container javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html).

Comment: i'm using `JmsTemplate` in `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, so what should i choose CachingConnectionFactory or SessionCaching in listnerContainer ? which one you think is faster ? what if i use both ?

Comment: As I said, if you need the template operations to run in the container transaction, you should use the caching factory with consumer caching turned off. If you don't need that, and you don't need to share a single connection, use the caching factory for the template and the raw vendor factory for the container.

Comment: i'm not using it in JEE server, not cant use vendorfactory, i suppose i have to use only CachingConnectionFactory here .... can i use both here ? imean  CachingConnectionFactory + sessionCaching in ListnerContainer ?

Comment: You must have a vendor factory - the CCF simply wraps the provider's factory (ActiveMQ, HornetQ etc). As I said, yes, you can, but don't cache consumers.

Comment: Yes, its IBMmq i'm using under CachingConnectionFactory :), hope it wont cause problem with transaction .. i'm using DB in listnerContainer, i always want db first then jms commit ? im using dbTransactionmanager in ListnerContainer..

Comment: Yes, that's fine, be sure to set `sessionTransacted` on the container and, as I said, if you perform `JmsTemplate` operations as well as DB and you want those operations to participate in the JMS transation, you __MUST__ use the same connection facrtory for the container and template. If you don't do template operations, or they run in a different transaction, then you can use the IBM factory in the container and caching factory in the template.